# Overlay UIView With Same Color As Primary UIImage Color In Background

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to overlay a UIView on a UIImage and want the UIView to have the same color as the UIImage. Similar to this:

[image]

I am doing this in a `TableView`. I found a couple of ways to do this with extensions and pods. I implemented each of these but it seems like the `UIView` colors were taking a while to render on the cell. Not sure if this is related to asynchronous calls or the methods I used. Has anyone seen similar issues when trying to implement a similar function?

Also, I think part of the issue is where I am setting the `UIView.backgroundColor`. I played around with it in my `configureCell()` function in my `PostCell` class.

```
func configureCell(post: Post, img: UIImage? = nil) {
    self.post = post

    self.postDescription.text = post.wineName
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.overImageView.backgroundColor = img?.averageColor
    }

    if img != nil {
        self.postImage.image = img
    } else {
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: post.imageUrl)
        ref.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("ERIC: Unable to download image from Firebase storage")
            } else {
                print("ERIC: Image downloaded from Firebase storage")
                if let imgData = data {
                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                        self.postImage.image = img
                        self.overImageView.backgroundColor = img.averageColor
                        FeedViewController.imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: post.imageUrl as NSString)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Should I be implementing the `UIView` color in `PostCell` (above) or `FeedViewController` (below)?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomMessageCell
    print("POSTS: \(posts[indexPath.row])")
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as? PostCell{
        if let img = FeedViewController.imageCache.object(forKey: post.imageUrl as NSString) {
            cell.configureCell(post: post, img: img)
        } else {
            cell.configureCell(post: post)
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }

}
```

Code for the average color:

```
extension UIImage {
    var averageColor: UIColor? {
        guard let inputImage = CIImage(image: self) else { return nil }
        let extentVector = CIVector(x: inputImage.extent.origin.x, y: inputImage.extent.origin.y, z: inputImage.extent.size.width, w: inputImage.extent.size.height)

        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaAverage", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: inputImage, kCIInputExtentKey: extentVector]) else { return nil }
        guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else { return nil }

        var bitmap = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
        let context = CIContext(options: [.workingColorSpace: kCFNull])
        context.render(outputImage, toBitmap: &bitmap, rowBytes: 4, bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: nil)

        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(bitmap[0]) / 255, green: CGFloat(bitmap[1]) / 255, blue: CGFloat(bitmap[2]) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(bitmap[3]) / 255)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you taking an average color of the image? If so, how are you getting this color?

Comment: @DevKyle I tried retrieving the average color in a couple of different spots - I added it to the `configureCell` above. I also added the extension I am using to retrieve the average color.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you are changing the background color in a background thread. UI changes like background colors must be changed on the main thread. Try:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.overImageView.backgroundColor = img.averageColor 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Okay, I added that bit of code (see edited `configureCell`). The `UIView` is changing colors but it is still slowing down considerably. Did I put it in the right place?

Comment: Can you try just setting a specified color? So for example, try setting the background color to blue rather than the image color. Let me know if it still slows down.

Comment: When I set a specified color it does not slow down.

Comment: Ok that means calculating the average color is causing the delay. You might look at either a different way to calculate, or different way to implement the color change.